# Hide table content / cut the content in angular js, Html

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Im new to angular, i have a table like this which is having angular data, its not having any controller or model. Its just displaying in html.

```
<table  width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" class="labels" align="center" id="locc">
  <tr style="color:#000;font-size:15px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-repeat:repeat-x" height="30" >
    <td colspan="4"  align="center"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color:#000;font-size:15px;font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background-color:gold;background-repeat:repeat-x"
      height="30" >
    <td  width="211"  align="center">COMMODITY</td>
    <td  width="149" align="center" valign="middle"  >BUY</td>
    <td  width="175" align="center" valign="middle" >SELL</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody ng-repeat="item in newsData | limitTo : 2" >
  <tr bgcolor="#FFFFFF" height="40"  >
    <td  align="center" style="background-image:url(images/td.png);color:#000;font-size:15px" >{{item.COMMODITY | limitTo: 18 }}</td>
    <td  align="center" valign="middle" style="color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="{{item.BCOL}}" ><div  >&nbsp;&nbsp;{{item.BUY}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>
    <td  align="center" valign="middle" style="color:#000000;font-size:20px" class="{{item.SCOL}}"  ><div >{{item.SELL}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</div></td>

  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The output of the following is like this..

[image]

By default all the data is coming under Commodity.. I want to display only the content like **999[GOLD][IMPORTED]**  and Cut the remaining text after that.

Comment: has the 999[GOLD][IMPORTED]  fixed length..?

Comment: surely you have a controller (where is `newsData` even coming from?), inside it you can format your data in a loop: `newsData[index].COMODITY = newsData[index].COMODITY.substring(0, newsData[index].COMODITY.indexOf('[IMPORTED]')+10)`

Comment: No, Can we remove the text which is coming after 999[GOLD][IMPORTED] ?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I cant access controller. Can we handle this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
then try limitTo filter:
This shows only number of characters from beginning,
what you want to display:
{{ item.COMMODITY | limitTo: 19 }}
since 999[GOLD][IMPORTED] has 19 characters
```

Comment: Worked thanks.. One more query.. Lets say i have 5 columns like that and i want to display only first and third. If i use limit after **newsData** like **newsData | limitTo : 2 **  this will display first two columns. But i want first and third.?

Comment: paste your newsData value.. then i can solve it for you

Comment: sorry its rows.. Like above pic is having 2 rows.

Comment: @SalmanRiyaz your rows are `<tr>` / `<tbody>`, so try adding next to ng-repeat: `ng-show="[1,3].indexOf($index)!=-1"` (instead of [1,3] you can have your own array that contains the elements that you want to show -> `... array.indexOf($index) ...`)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey Worked like charm..  Thank u so much